# How to use a selection to generate an sql query

Tags: php, html, sql

I need to use the selection from and HTML select element as one of the variables in my sql query. Meaning if the user selects "Iphone" from the list, I want to query to be something like select * where name = Iphone.
I do not know how to go about this, thank you.

This code creates the select based on the query:

```
    <option disabled selected value> -- Select a forum -- </option>
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","db");
        if (!$con) {
            die('Connection failed: ' . mysqli_connect_error() . '<br>');
            }
$productName='SELECT p.name 
FROM product as p 
JOIN ownedproducts as o on o.productID = p.productID 
WHERE usersID =2;';
        $result=mysqli_query($con, $productName);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                  unset($id);
                  $id = $row['name'];
                  echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$id.'</option>';
                  }
</select>
```

I would like to take what the user selects, including multiple selections, and  build a table based on that something like this where the AND p.name = selected is replaced with what would actually work in this case. I think javascript is the way to go but I do not know enough.

```
<?php 
$query1 = $db->query('SELECT p.productID, p.name, p.company, o.prodtype AS Type
FROM ownedproducts AS o
JOIN product as p ON p.productID = o.productID
WHERE o.usersID = 2
AND p.name = selected');

    while ($row = $query1->fetch()) 
{
    if . $row['name'] . = selected:    
    echo "<tr id=" . $row['productID'] . ">";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['company'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Type'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

Edited for more detail.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know how to get started/have you already done that, such as setting up a database server (or using some hosting provider), creating a database, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Though, I am not sure what are you asking for but select statement for exact match will be like below=>

```
select * from tablename where name='Iphone';
```

or if you want partial match then you can use wildcard(`%`) and `like` operator  given below =>

```
select * from tablename where name like '%Iphone%';
```